# Google Play books missing table of contents for PDF uploads

Tags: pdf, google-play-books

I have uploaded several books (PDFs) using the Google Play Books Upload service. However, I found out that none of these show a "table of content" bookmark normally found in PDFs. (I see a valid TOC when I use another reader.)

Can someone please confirm if Google Play Books supports "table of contents" for uploaded PDFs?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry mate, as of June 2015, Google Books doesn't have support for a ToC for uploaded PDFs. I would recommend converting the PDF an EPUB using an app such as Calibre.